# Regarding proving linear independence of product $G_k-12r$×$\Delta^r$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I am self studying Apostol modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I have a doubt in text of Chapter -6

Apostol mentions that it is easy to prove that  products $G_{k-12r}$×$\Delta^r$   are Linearly Independent using $\Delta(i \infty) $ =0 but $G_{2r}(i \infty )  \neq  0 $ .

But if I assume $c_r $ × $G_{k-12r}$×$\Delta^r$ =0 and put $\tau$ = i$\infty $ then I will get both RHS and LHS =0 .

Edit 1 -> The statement which I don't know how to prove is related to proving this theorem.

[image]

So, can someone please tell how to prove their linear independence.

Comment: @user714237 what does order of vanishing at $\infty $ means?

Comment: Look at their $q$-expansions. The order of vanishing is the order of the zero of the function at $q=0$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown can you please add some more details to what you have mentioned in your comment. I am not able to think about it.

Comment: I deleted a bunch of comments. Please try to be convey your sentiments and opinions in as friendly a way as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is about Theorem 6.3 in Section 6.4 on page 117.
The proof ends on page 118 as follows

> To show there is at most one such representation we need only
>   verify that the products $G_{k-12r}\Delta^r$ are linearly
>   independent. This follows easily from the fact that
>   $\Delta(i\infty)=0$ but $G_{2r}(i\infty)\ne0$. details are left
>   as an exercise for the reader.

As a comment by Lord Shark indicates, the explanation comes
from the $q$ expansion of the products. That is, if
$\tau=i\infty$ then $q=0$. The statement
$G_{2r} i\infty)\ne0$ comes from equation
$(48)$ on page 69 where $G_{2k} = 2\zeta(2k)$ plus higher
order terms in the $q$ expansion. The other fact comes from
equation $(8)$ on page 51 where $\Delta(\tau) = (2\pi)^{12}$
times a $q$ series which begins with $q$. These two facts give
us that $G_{k-12}\Delta^r$ has a leading term of $q^r$ times a
constant. Any sequence of functions with this property will be
linearly independent. This is analogous to the statement that
any sequence of polynomials of different degrees will be
linearly independent and the proof is essentially the same.

Comment: thank you very much!!  I was confused

Comment: Can you please answer this question of me if you have some time to spare.it has a bounty of 50 over it which will expire in 14 hours.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502986/doubt-in-proof-of-siegel-of-dedekind-eta-function-in-transformation-s-frac1