# Doubt in proof of Siegel of Dedekind eta function in transformation $S=-\frac{1}{\tau} $

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dedekind-eta-function

I am self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I am having a doubt in Theorem 3.1 . ( I have doubt only in highlighted part of image 3)

> adding Image of theorem
>    [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
> I have doubt only in highlighted part of theorem in image 3 . I am not able to understand how Apostol writes that the function $zF_n(z) $ has as n->$\infty$ , the limit 1/8 on the edges connecting y, i, ?

Can someone please tell how to deduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the question is a simple one. The
function $\,\exp(n z)\to 0\,$ as $\,n\to \infty\,$ iff
the real part of $\,z\,$ is negative. This implies that
$\,\cot(nz)\to i\,$ as $\,n\to \infty\,$ if the real part
of $\,z\,$ is negative, but $\,-i\,$ if the real part of
$\,z\,$ is positive. This implies that the first factor
of cotangent in $\,zF_n(z)\,$ converges to $\,i\,$ if the
real part of $\,z\,$ is positive and to $\,-i\,$ if the
real part of $\,z\,$ is negative. The second factor of cotangent converges to $\,i\,$ if the imaginary part of $\,z\,$ is
negative and to $\,-i\,$ if the imaginary part of $\,z\,$
is positive.

Finally $\,zF_n(z)\to \frac18\,$ or $\,-\frac18\,$ according
to the quadrant that $\,z\,$ is in.

Comment: bounty expiring in 26 minutes. Couldn't read your answer as I am travelling and it's past midnight but awarding bounty to you as you have answered . Thanks